# My chart doesn't want to fill up with data

Tags: javascript, json, flask

So I'm trying to build a flask app and used a tutorial to create a chart. I've seperated the chart in a javescript file as instructed but for some reason the chart doesn't fill up with the data.

I think that the Javascript file is the problem because if I go to the `'/get_data'` page
the data is there. It looks like that the javescript file doesn't want to see the payload with the data.

```
payload:    "{\"data\": [5578, 5267, 734, 784, 433], \"labels\": [\"Africa\", \"Asia\", \"Europe\", \"Latin America\", \"North America\"]}"
```

can somebody take a look at the code?

My Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var _data;
   var _labels;
  $.ajax({
   url: '/get_data',
   type: "get",
   data: {vals: ''},
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response.payload);
     _data = full_data['data'];
     _labels = full_data['labels'];
   },

 });
 new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
 data: {
   labels: _labels,
   datasets: [
   {
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
   data: _data
   }
   ]
   },
    options: {
    legend: { display: true },
     title: {
      display: true,
     text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
   }
  }
 });
});
```

My flask app looks like this.

```
import os
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/simple_chart', methods=['GET'])
def simple_chart():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
  labels = ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"]
  data = [5578,5267,734,784,433]
  return flask.jsonify({'payload':json.dumps({'data':data, 'labels':labels})})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New</title>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script1.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="bar-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
    </div>


   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What jumps out looking at code fragments is that the unnecessary complication around JSON encoding/decoding.

First, if you use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.ajax()`, the first level of JSON decoding done for you automatically. The second level (via `json.dumps()`) isn't necessary. I.e., instead of

```
return flask.jsonify({'payload':json.dumps({'data':data, 'labels':labels})})
```

you can use

```
return flask.jsonify(data=data, labels=labels)
```

and Flask will do the right thing (which in this case means there's no payload to decode on the page-side, which then looks something like

```
success: function(already_json) {
    _data = already_json['data'];
    _labels = already_json['labels'];
},
```

Comment: Thank Dave, I didn't read the already_json function correctly, but it works now. The only problem is that the data doesn't load in. do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The chart gets created right after the request for data is made, but mostly likely before any response is processed. If you can't find an example of asynchronous use in the Chart.js docs, in your position I'd delay creating the Chart until I had data (e.g., by doing in the success calback).

Comment: So that means I need to create a delay of some sort in the success callback (i'm not very good in javascript so that is why i ask)

Comment: Yes. I'd put the code to build the graph in a function, and call it from the success callback.

Comment: so i've tried it but still it doesn't load my data. my code looks like this now: $(document).ready(function(){
   var _data;
   var _labels;
  $.getJSON({
   url: '/get_data',
   type: "get",
   data: {vals: ''},
   success: function(already_json) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    _data = already_json['data'];
    _labels = already_json['labels'];
    },2000);
   },

 });

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()`? All that does is delay setting `_data` and `_labels` by two seconds. Instead, call a function that creates the chart.